# Image is not centered with background

Tags: html, css

I am centering an image in the following code but as I center it the background fades.I have managed to put the image in the center but with the background color. How to fix this ? Please do tell how to position image as well?

**HTML**

```
<section id="contact">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-5 centered">
<img src="something.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact
{
    background-color:black;
    }

.container 
{
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%,0);
    }

#contact  .centered
{
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

#contact img
{
    border-radius:50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: there is no `height` on any of your containers so that's why you can't see the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you give outer position absolute and container position relative , it can help you and for left, top 50% values, make them in the outer div because you put them one within the other

```
#contact{
        background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    }

.container 
{
        text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%,0); */
    }
```

Comment: give some height and width for section @user3755882 The image I used when I was trying has no background that's why I saw it

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hemnathmouli/jp7gydwf/

Try this.

```
<div class = "image">
<img src = "http://www.mountainguides.com/photos/everest-south/c2_2011b.jpg" alt="myimage"> 
<span class = "caption">
Hello World.!
</span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.image{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: table;
}

.caption{
    position: absolute;
background: black;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will work `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`